# MediaFoundation: cleaning up after Media Sources

Tags: windows-7, ms-media-foundation

Ok, so I get the gist of MediaFoundation:

When I start my App I create an IMFMediaSession.

When I want to play a file I create an IMFMediaSource, create the necessary IMFTopology, and I set it to the IMFMediaSession. Depending on the flag used (dwSetTopologyFlags) the new media source will either play immediately or just get added to a queue to be played by the MediaSession when the existing topologies/mediaSources are done playing.

Now my issue is cleaning up after old media sources.

Is there an event that is sent by the MediaSession right before the topology used is about to be removed? That way I could access the media source from there and call ShutDown on it (thus avoiding memory leaks) without having to keep references to previous mediaSessions myself in my code.

**//=============================================================================== Update:**

According to MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
I need to call ShutDown on any IMFMediaSource I create, before releasing it.

With this in-mind, mixing MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_FLAGS (immediate/clear_current with no flags) can cause a memory-leak, as the Session removes topologies from its queue without my application having the chance to call shutdown on their sources.

Also, if I call Shutdown on the current mediaSource before the next mediaSource's topology has been set (i.e. before I get the MESessionTopologyStatus event) then I can't playback the next mediaSource. Why? I don't know, msdn does not explain what resources are released when I call shudown on a mediaSource, so I guess something I still need in order to play the next mediaSource is being released...

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that if you do not call Shutdown on Source, you will have memory leak. Check my project MFNode. There is a custom MediaSession (MFNodePlayer project).
If you uncomment the call to Shutdown on the source, you will see memory leak.

A lot of source expect you call Shutdown because you need to wait stop message from the source (they are usually asynchronous).
If you try to use the the source before it stops, you will face some strange error/behaviour and memory leak.

You have to wait the source to stop, in order to have a stable application. And calling Shutdown on source is here for that.